# Construct a sequence of real analytic functions solving the equation with a condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sequence-of-function, elliptic-equations

Consider the Laplace equation in two dimensions:
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0$$.
Construct a sequence of real analytic functions $(u_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ with $u_k:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ solving the equation
such that for any $l\in\mathbb{N}{:}$
$$\begin{aligned}\sup_x\left|(\partial_x)^lu_k(x,0)\right|+\sup_x\left|(\partial_x)^l\partial_yu_k(x,0)\right|\to0\end{aligned}$$
as $k \to \infty$, but such that for any $e>0$, $\sup_x|u_k(x,\epsilon)|\to\infty.$ What does this mean for the well-posedness of the Cauchy problem for Laplace’s equation?

**Attempt:**
I was given a hint to first solve the Cauchy problem for the initial surface ${y = 0}$ with data
$u(x, 0)$ = $\cos kx$, $u_y(x, 0) = 0$ by seeking a solution of the form $u(x, y) = X(x)Y (y).$

After substituting in the last equation I got $-X(x)Y^{\prime\prime}(y)+X^{\prime\prime}(x)Y(y)=0$, but I don't have any ideas how to move forward in this problem

Comment: What is your question: (a) how to construct such a sequence of functions, or (b) what does it mean to the well-posedness of the Cauchy problem?

Comment: I am having most trouble with a) for now, I was hoping it automatically gives hints on b), but I may be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the hint, let's seek a solution to Laplace's equation of the form $u(x,y)=Y(y)\cos kx$. Substituting this ansatz in the PDE, we obtain the equation $(-k^2Y(y)+Y''(y))\cos kx=0$, which has as general solution $Y(y)=C_1\cosh ky +C_2\sinh ky.$ Imposing the conditions $u(x,0)=\cos kx, u_y(x,0)=0$, we find $C_1=1$ and $C_2=0$, so $u(x,y)=\cos kx \cosh ky$. Since Laplace's equation is linear, we have the freedom to multiply $u$ by a constant. Using this freedom, we define $u_k$ as
$$
u_k(x,y)=C_k\cos kx \cosh ky. \tag{1}
$$
Now we must show that it is possible to choose $C_k$ so that $(1)$ satisfies the conditions
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sup_{x\in{\mathbb{R}}}\left|(\partial_x)^{\ell}u_k(x,0)\right|+\sup_{x\in{\mathbb{R}}}\left|(\partial_x)^{\ell}\partial_yu_k(x,0)\right|\right)=0\qquad \forall\ell\in\mathbb{N}, \tag{2}
$$
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{x\in{\mathbb{R}}}|u_k(x,\epsilon)|=\infty\qquad \forall\epsilon>0, \tag{3}
$$
that is,
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}C_k\,k^{\ell}=0\qquad \forall\ell\in\mathbb{N}, \tag{$2'$}
$$
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}C_k\cosh k\epsilon=\infty\qquad \forall\epsilon>0. \tag{$3'$}
$$
It's easy to verify that $C_k=e^{-\sqrt{k}}$ satisfies both $(2')$ and $(3')$.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask how did you apply hyperbolic trig identities to general solution, I am stuck at getting $Y(y)=C_1e^{ky}+C_2e^{-ky}$

Comment: $\cosh u=\frac{e^u+e^{-u}}{2}$ and $\sinh u=\frac{e^u-e^{-u}}{2}$, hence $e^{\pm u}=\cosh u \pm \sinh u$.